# N-channel MOSFET not fully OFF

Tags: mosfet-driver

I have this very simple circuit - actually there are 6 of them on a board.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f01jwr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The MCU is connected to an MCU, and it is used to drive RGB led strips with PWM singals. My problem is that the MOSFET is not fully turned off. Or so it seems. When the MCU line is high and the Q1 transistor is fully turned on, then the gate of the M1 MOSFET is at 0.6V (one junction). Even though the threshold voltage of M1 should be about 2V, it is not 100% turned off at 0.6V. The result is that the LED strip glimmers a bit. It is almost nothing, but the LED strip is 20 meters long, and all of that small glimmering adds up. Basically, I cannot use this circuit as it is, because of that small glimmering. It becomes very distrubing in room that is used to watch movies in the dark.

Would it be possible to turn the FET fully off? My only idea is to use a dual power supply, and put the emitter of the Q1 transistor at -0.7V instead of 0V. However, creating a -0.7V supply just for this seems to be an overkill.

Comment: Why not replace the 2N2222 with a VN2222 logic-level MOSFET? It should control the IRFZ44 quite well and will require much less current from your MCU. (Put a weak pull-down resistor from G-S on the VN2222 to keep it off if the MCU output is tri-state).

Comment: I agree with Adam about using an NMOS instead of the NPN, also **if** the PWM frequency is not so high (which it probably isn't) you could increase the value of R1 as well to make less current flow, that would also decrease the gate voltage.

Comment: "When the MCU line is high" the BJT should be on and not open circuit.

Comment: Ok so using 6 pieces of vn2222 would probably be easy and it would solve the problem. Although, 6 pcs vn2222 would probably cost more than a -0.7V supply.

Comment: Using words like "open" and "closed" to describe transistors is confusing. Do you mean open like a valve or open circuit? Also, you can't just say "the transistor" when there are two transistors in your circuit.

Comment: First, **please please please** edit your post.  An "open circuit" is one that does not conduct electricity.  An "open valve" is one that passes fluid.  To avoid confusion *no one in electronics* talks about an "open transistor" unless they mean on that has failed as an open circuit.  Go through your post, and replace "open" with "on" and "closed" with "off" -- that will un-confuse those of us who are trying to help.

Comment: I have replaced "closed" with "turned off" and "opened" with "turned on".

Comment: 2.2k is a very strong pull-up. 50k should work a lot better.

Comment: What happens if you make R1 much larger? (200k-1M) - it's a voltage divider with the transistor when it's on (or better yet replace the bipolar with a fet

Comment: _"Even though the threshold voltage of M1 should be about 2V, it is not 100% turned off at 0.6V."_ - Be aware that at Vgs(th) the mosfet is _not fully off_. Vgs(th) is usually defined at a fixed, small but non-zero Ids. In this case (according to a random IRFZ44 datasheet I found) 250µA, which might be enough to make your LEDs glimmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "MCU" signal is going up to 3.3V then Q1 should be fully saturated, and it should pull its collector down to 0.2V or so.  If it's only going down to 0.6V then you have a defective transistor in there, you've put it in backwards (emitter where the collector should be, collector where the emitter should be), or your MCU doesn't have enough drive to bring the "MCU" line up to its rail (it should be almost at the rail; it certainly should be within 200mV, i.e. 3.1V for a 3.3V rail, 4.8V for a 5V rail).

I suspect you just plugged Q1 in backwards.  Double-check your pinout.  Then measure the voltage at MCU.

Comment: Q1 is not backwards. MCU line was 2V. After increasing that to 3.3V, the M1 gate went down to 30mV. But even at 30mV, I see some light coming out from the LEDs. But they are almost invisible now.

Comment: What is the voltage at the source of M1 when it should be off?

Comment: At the gate of m1: 34mV when off, 9.3V when on.

Comment: At the source of m1 when on: 13 to 19mV (depending on the color)

Comment: I was asking what is the voltage at the source of M1 when it should be **off** (i.e., not conducting current).  A better question would be what's the voltage across the string.  An even better question would be to ask you to measure current as well.  That thing has to be really efficient at making light from precious little current -- putting a 1k-ohm resistor in parallel with the string may be enough to force it all the way off.

Comment: Voltage at source of M1 when it should be off is 3.6V (instead of 12 minus diode drop) How is that possible? :-(

Comment: Can you either easily measure the current, or put some modest resistance (like \$1\mathrm{k}\Omega\$ in parallel with your LED string?  There should be a minuscule current going through M1.  It could be that you cooked it before -- if it's easy to swap out you may want to do so.

Comment: Ok I'll replace but I can only do that tomorrow

Comment: If the LED strip has a switching supply in it then it may be quite efficient at using every erg of available energy.

Comment: Okay, so replacing the FET did not help. Putting a resistor in paralel did not help. It was all my fault! I was using a voltage divider on the MCU line for testing. I have used too big resistors in the divider.  It was really 3.3V when unloaded, but much less when connected to the MCU line. After making sure that it stays at 3.3V, all the glimmering went away. I could learn a lot from this, thank you!